Has anyone ever seen something like this in an actual game?

I came across this puzzle at IM Yaacov Norowitz's site (https://www.yaacattack.com/dachastairway), and although it's really interesting, I'm curious if anyone has seen this in an actual game.

Could you formulate "this" more precise? The Problemists call the basic idea an "Indian". Thousands of chess problems must exist, if not more. I'm sure that happened OTB. But you additionally have the stairway. This also has happened OTB, any Polerio win may count. Thus: Indian, stairway, or both?
